# How to get default constraint name without altering database?

Tags: sqlalchemy

How do I get a constraint's default name as generated using `MetaData`'s naming convention? I'm dynamically creating a constraint, and then looking it up, but to look it up I need its name. I need to identify the constraint uniquely, without giving it a user-specified name.

I tried appending it to an SQLALchemy `Table` with `Table.append_constraint`, but even so its name field is `None`. I expect it to have a name generated according to the naming convention. Example:

```py
naming_convention = {                                                                                                                       
    "uq": '%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_uq'
}

metadata = MetaData(naming_convention = naming_convention)

table = Table("table1", metadata, Column('col1', Integer))
constraint = UniqueConstraint('col1', name = None)
table.append_constraint(constraint)
default_constraint_name = constraint.name

default_constraint_name == 'table1_col1s_uq'
# False
default_constraint_name == None
# True
```

Comment: Try `table.compile()` followed by `default_constraint_name = list(table.constraints)[0].name`

Comment: @GordThompson `compile()` didn't help. What's funny is that the code sample above actually works, but in production (more complicated case) it doesn't. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the introspected name from the database to be certain. For example, in my case (default naming convention), without introspection the uniqueness constraint's name is `None`, while with:

```py
async with engine.connect() as conn:
    tables = await conn.run_sync(
        lambda sync_conn: inspect(sync_conn).get_unique_constraints('table1')
    )
```

the name is as assigned by the database. In your case, perhaps the naming convention was introduced after the constraint was created in production.